# Set WordPress default settings before installing

Tags: wordpress, settings

I'm making a custom wordpress install package for users to setup a wordpress site on their own. Is it possible to change some settings in Wordpress php code before we actually install it ?

For Example, 
if we can change default theme to my-custom-made-theme, 
not offical twentysixteen;
or change the timezone to what I want,

me and users can both save tons of time about 'basic settings'
without set though dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file /wp-includes/default-constants.php

Find this line of code

if ( !defined('WP_DEFAULT_THEME') )
        define( 'WP_DEFAULT_THEME', 'twentyten' );

And change the wp_defualt_theme value to the FOLDER of the theme you want to use.

Comment: NEVER EVER edit the CORE files